# How save data from form in headless Craft via Vue.js

Tags: craft3, database, form, vue

I have front-end form on Vue.js and Craft CMS for the backend. I need form. And I want to save data from the form in Craft CMS. How to save data from user frontend to backend on Craft CMS?

Comment: Does this help at all? https://nystudio107.com/blog/using-vuejs-2-0-with-craft-cms

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

You would not use the headless API to submit content in into Craft, as neither the GraphQL or Element APIs support writing.

The frontend entry form functionality is [fairly well documented](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/entry-form.html). You would just need your frontend to build out a post request including the correct action, CSRF token, and whatever fields are needed. The action endpoint will automatically return a JSON response if it is posted to by an AJAX request.